# Finding the maximum value of each row and reshaping the matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, reshape

Say we have the following matrix:

```
2 5
5 3 
6 3
6 4
```

What I'm trying to do is:

**1- Find the maximum value of each row**
For this part, I think we can do the following?

```
[r,c] = size(u);
for i=1:c
for j=1:r
index=1;
for i=1:c
    for j=1:r
       [value,position]=max(u(j,:)); 
       membershipMatrix(index)=value; 
       index=index+1;
    end
end
```

**2- Then, I want to reshape the above matrix to a `2x2` matrix.**
I think we can here do the following?

```
reshape(I,2,2)
```

At the beginning it sounds trivial. I tried performing step **1** above on a `65536x2` matrix, but ended up with a `131072x1`matrix, where I was originally planning to `reshape` into a `256x256` matrix, as I thought that I will end up with a `65536x1` matrix for the first step.

What could be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @MedSWEng - I would be interested in hearing your opinion on this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184802/ban-user-for-continuously-asking-questions-which-show-no-effort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in Matlab - vectorize!

```
mx = max( u, [], 2 ); % find max along rows of u
reshape( mx, 256, 256 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you have used `[]` in `max`, what would that denote?

Comment: @Med-SWEng see what [matlab doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) has to say: third use case.

Comment: It mentions what is explicitly shown in that it finds the maximum along a specific dimension, but doesn't describe the reason of inserting `[]`. Thanks

Comment: It is related to the second matrix.  See MAX(X,Y) in the help, it says that either X or Y can be a scalar.

Comment: @Med-SWEng what is the difference between `max( [0 1], 2 )` and `max( [0 1], [], 2)`? try it and I believe it will answer your question.